# changes to parent prototype adds property to children

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

**Preface:**

I have an Object, lets call it 'A'. I add a function to it's prototype via `A.__proto__.AsDf = -1;`. Now all children of 'A' also have a property 'AsDf === -1`.

I've been reading around and I think I understand what is going on but I was hoping to get some confirmation and maybe more information about how it works (assuming that's not all there is to it).

**Question(s):**

- Is this because `A.__proto__` is Object, meaning I'm adding 'AsDf = -1;' to all Objects?
- Also, if this is the case, would doing something along the lines of creating a new object identical to 'A' with a prototype other than Object make it add 'AsDf' to it only and not its children? (assuming all children are objects and not the new object of course).

Comment: Could you post some code detailing exactly how you create A and its children? The use of __proto__ is discouraged: depending on how you're using it, I can think of a few possible answers.

Comment: I'm creating A via `ko.mapping.fromJSON`. My use of **proto** is probably the discouraged use, I'm still working on learning prototypal inheritance. I don't plan on keeping my current implementation it's just temporary until I learn a better way. Which I'm close to doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't go via `__proto__`, either go via `A.constructor.prototype` (if available) or `Object.getPrototypeOf(A)`
2. If `Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Object.prototype` then setting properties here means *every* object inherits them
3. How are you creating `A`? It might be better to do `A = Object.create({});`, giving yourself a *prototype* you can work with safely.
4. How do you have "Children" of `A` if it's an *Object* and not a *Function*? You mean `child = A.someProperty = {};` ?

---

Example using `Object.create({})`

```
var A = Object.create({});
A.foo; // undefined
Object.getPrototypeOf(A).foo = 'bar';
A.foo; // "bar"
A.fizz = {};
A.fizz.foo; // undefined
// but note that because fizz was made with {} we have
Object.getPrototypeOf(A.fizz) === Object.prototype; // true
// even though we made it so that
Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Object.prototype; // false
// i.e. the only relation between them is the property reference
```

Comment: 3. I'm creating them using mapping plugin `fromJSON` because they are my viewModels in MVC coded in C#. 4. Yes, they are properties of 'A' that are objects. I started slowly realizing the answer to my question as I typed it out, but I figured it couldn't hurt to post it anyways instead of deleting it. Figured I (or someone else) might learn something from it. Also, is `Object.create({});` the only way to create an object? What about something like `Object.create(Object);`? Does this have a different effect?